# Angular 4 material project is not compiling

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular-material2

I am new to the angular. I have made the set up for angular project.First time when i fired the  ng serve --open command , it opened the url and was working fine. After that i have installed angular material .Now if i run the application it is taking me the new browser tab. But showing compilation error. Could someone please help me to sort out the exact issue. I was trying this past 3 hours. please help.

> npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
>   npm install --save @angular/animations
>   npm install --save hammerjs
>   npm install --save @angular/flex-layout@latest

[image]

**my app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material'; 
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import 'hammerjs';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    FlexLayoutModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**my package.json**

```
{
  "name": "con-fusion",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

**My app.component.html**

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{title}}!
  </h1>
  <img width="300" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTAgMjUwIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNERDAwMzEiIGQ9Ik0xMjUgMzBMMzEuOSA2My4ybDE0LjIgMTIzLjFMMTI1IDIzMGw3OC45LTQzLjcgMTQuMi0xMjMuMXoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjQzMwMDJGIiBkPSJNMTI1IDMwdjIyLjItLjFWMjMwbDc4LjktNDMuNyAxNC4yLTEyMy4xTDEyNSAzMHoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCAgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgZD0iTTEyNSA1Mi4xTDY2LjggMTgyLjZoMjEuN2wxMS43LTI5LjJoNDkuNGwxMS43IDI5LjJIMTgzTDEyNSA1Mi4xem0xNyA4My4zaC0zNGwxNy00MC45IDE3IDQwLjl6IiAvPgogIDwvc3ZnPg==">

  <md-toolbar color="primary"> <span>Ristorante Con Fusion</span> </md-toolbar>
  </div>
<h2>Here are some links to help you start: </h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/tutorial">Tour of Heroes</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki">CLI Documentation</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://blog.angular.io/">Angular blog</a></h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**My style.scss**

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';


body { 
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0; 
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; 

}
```

Comment: you don't need the material module just ditch it and everything should work

Answer (score 2):

See [Getting Started With Angular Material 2
(**September 4, 2017**)](https://alligator.io/angular/angular-material-2/)

> 3. Custom Material Module
>
> Prior to **Angular Material 2 Beta 3**, there was a global MaterialModule
>   that could be imported in the app module to make the components
>   available. The downside to that is that tree-shaking is not efficient
>   enough to remove all the unused code.
>
> MaterialModule has therefore been deprecated in favor of defining a
>   project-specific custom material module where you import and export
>   only the needed components. Here’s what our module can look like:

Unfortunately the official guide is a not as explicit as the above article. You need to go through each component you use and import the module for for it, then add it to the imports section of AppModule.

Looks like you are just using Toolbar, so the only module you need is MdToolbarModule.

```
import { MdToolbarModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    MdToolbarModule,
  ],
```

Essentially, as the article above explains, you 'roll-your-own' MaterialModule. The main purpose seems to be avoiding deploying of unused material components in your app.

Comment: Thanks very much Richard. It is working fine now after using MdToolbarModule. After 4 hours struggle. It is working. Now i will get good sleep. Thanks a lot buddy.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that problem out. I am using beta 2, so would hit this on next minor upgrade and would have also spent time figuring it out. I don't know who down-voted your question, seems a little off.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `MaterialModule` is not importable anymore, you need to import the only module that you want, you can see this info here:

[CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes)

So, if you want material, import only the component module that you want, you can see the components list here:
https://material.angular.io/components

as for example, if I want material input, you go to [API tab](https://material.angular.io/components/input/api) see what you want to import:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material'; 
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import 'hammerjs';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    FlexLayoutModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And this is the official plunker example: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/o077B6uEiiIgkC0S06dd?p=preview

Anyway, I don't see where you are using the material component in your HTML, so not sure which one you want to use.

Comment: Thanks Al-Mothafar for your help. It is working now.